# Using PowerShell ImportExcel module, how do I get Excel column number by heading name?

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm using the [Import-Excel PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.8.1) .

How do I get the number of the column by the header name?  E.g. I want to add a "Manager" column after the "Name" column.  If I know "Name" is 4th column, I can use

```
$Spreadsheet=($MyArray | Export-Excel -PassThru $true)
$Spreadsheet.Workbook.Worksheets["MyWorksheetName"].InsertColumn(5,1)
```

How can I however do it more dynamically based on column name?

Comment: Why not create the column before exporting the data?

Comment: I suppose creating the "column" in the array might be an option for the insert, but complex things when inserting formulas with relative references.  Also, I want to set the format of some columns, which can't be done in the array before exporting, although I could potentially reference the array to work out the expected column, before inserting any new columns, etc.